# Android App crashes when unplugged from usb

Tags: android, crash, usb

My app starts an `Activity` that uses two `Fragments` to provide details to selected items from a `List`.

On startup the app **reads** a `SQLite` DB on the external storage.
Furthermore it collects data from xml files on the external storage.

That all works great and smooth :)

But since i am working with an abstract class to reuse code in my detail `Fragments` the app starts acting strange.
When i **plug OR unplug the device from usb** while a detail `Fragment` is open or hidden - the app crashes.

> "Sorry, The application xyz has stopped unexpectedly. ... Please try
>   again"

I think it's connected to the detail `Fragments`. I don't know that for sure because the debugger or logging wont work if you unplug the device :D

But all other functions work normally.

What happens to the app if you unplug the device? Maybe i can intervene there...

*AbstractDetailFragment*:

```
public AbstractWISDetailFragment(ChooseData cData) {
        this.data = cData;
    }

@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        setDetail();
        view.setClickable(true);
    }

protected abstract void setDetail();
```

*ImplFragment*:

```
public ActorDetailFragment(ChooseData data) {
    super(data);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.akteur_detail, container, false);
    return view;
}
@Override
protected void setDetail() {
    // something
    ...
}
```

### edit:

Here is my logcat entry from the moment i touch the list item to instanciate the detail fragment:

```
I/InputReader(  305): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0, pending(waiting
finished signal)=0
I/InputDispatcher(  305): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, c
hannel '41a8fc30 ...ChooseActivity (server)'
I/InputDispatcher(  305): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, c
hannel 'TouchIntercepter (server)'
I/InputReader(  305): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1, pending(waiting
finished signal)=0
I/InputDispatcher(  305): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, c
hannel '41a8fc30 ...ChooseActivity (server)'
I/InputDispatcher(  305): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, c
hannel 'TouchIntercepter (server)'
D/WIS_ActorList( 2686): new actor item data set (process reseted)
D/WIS_ChooseActivity( 2686): ProcessButton enabled
D/WIS_ChooseActivity( 2686): ProcessStartButton disabled
D/WIS_ChooseActivity( 2686): ProcessStartButton disabled
D/HierarchicalStateMachine(  305): handleMessage: E msg.what=65619
D/HierarchicalStateMachine(  305): processMsg: ConnectedState
D/WifiStateMachine(  305): ConnectedState{ what=65619 when=-3ms arg1=4 }
D/HierarchicalStateMachine(  305): handleMessage: X
D/HierarchicalStateMachine(  305): handleMessage: E msg.what=65619
D/HierarchicalStateMachine(  305): processMsg: ConnectedState
D/WifiStateMachine(  305): ConnectedState{ what=65619 when=-3ms arg1=4 }
D/HierarchicalStateMachine(  305): handleMessage: X
D/dalvikvm( 2305): GC_EXPLICIT freed 329K, 9% free 6875K/7495K, paused 7ms+2ms
W/PowerManagerService(  305): Timer 0x3->0x3|0x1
D/HierarchicalStateMachine(  305): handleMessage: E msg.what=65619
D/HierarchicalStateMachine(  305): processMsg: ConnectedState
D/WifiStateMachine(  305): ConnectedState{ what=65619 when=-4ms arg1=4 }
D/HierarchicalStateMachine(  305): handleMessage: X
D/HierarchicalStateMachine(  305): handleMessage: E msg.what=65619
D/HierarchicalStateMachine(  305): processMsg: ConnectedState
D/WifiStateMachine(  305): ConnectedState{ what=65619 when=-4ms arg1=4 }
D/HierarchicalStateMachine(  305): handleMessage: X
D/HierarchicalStateMachine(  305): handleMessage: E msg.what=65619
D/HierarchicalStateMachine(  305): processMsg: ConnectedState
D/WifiStateMachine(  305): ConnectedState{ what=65619 when=-4ms arg1=4 }
D/HierarchicalStateMachine(  305): handleMessage: X
```

If i unplug the device logcat kills itself.

Comment: Would you please enclose the logcat? Its a coincidence that unplugging crashes - usb connector in the "departure lounge"?

Comment: I dont think its a  coincidence. does unpluging reset the running activiy? i'll post the log later.

Comment: Look, there is not enough information in the logcat to pinpoint the source of the problem!

Comment: could it be that the activity is being reset and the fragments remain in the manager.
that way it could trigger a null pointer because the data object the fragment is reading from no longer exists!?

somebody knows something about that?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, when unplug the device the active activity will be restored. If - as in my case - you dont use *setArgument* and deliver *Bundles* to your fragments, there will be problems.
Accordingly, i had something similar as a null pointer, because my fragment could not reinitialize iteself and its data object passed via constructor.
Eclipse told me not to use non-standard constructors. this way a basic data object exange via parameter wont work.

solution:
Just exchange data with a Bundle (thats how its ment to be done):

```
Bundle extra = new Bundle();
extra.putSerializable("myData" this.data);
Fragment fragment = new fragment ();
fragment.setArguments(extra);
```

tada - all works fine.
if you keep that in mind in all your activitys and intends you wont run into any truble.

hf